# Exception thrown: write access violation. temp was nullptr

Tags: c++, c++14

I am getting an error in the `insert()` function in the `else` statement.

Here is the struct:

```cpp
struct Node
{
    int data;
    Node* next;
};
Node* head = NULL;
```

and here is the function:

```cpp
void insert(int data)
{
    Node* New = new Node();
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        New->data = data;
        head = New;
    }
    else
    {
        // down here where the error occured
        Node* temp = new Node();
        temp = head;
        while(temp != NULL)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp->data = data;
        temp->next = New;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop:

```
while(temp != NULL)
```

terminates when `temp` becomes equal to `nullptr` (note you better use this constant in C++ instead of `NULL`) and immediately after that loop you dereference `temp`. Also without any reason you assign result of `new` to `temp` and immediately loose it the next line of code (leading to a memory leak). And you should always assign `data` to the new item, not `temp` (which suppose to be the last item) Your logic should be something like:

```
void insert(int data)
{
    Node* New = new Node();
    New->data = data;     // note you better do these 2 lines in constructor
    New->next = nullptr; 
    if (head == nullptr)
    {
        head = New;
        return;
    }
    Node* temp = head; 
    while( temp->next != nullptr ) // look for the last item
        temp = temp->next; 
    temp->next = New;
}
```

Comment: And then the code can be *greatly* simplified: `void insert(int data) { Node **temp = &head; while (*temp) { temp = &((*temp)->next); } *temp = new Node{data, nullptr}; }`

Comment: @RemyLebeau agree but that could be too complex for OP, looks like pointers is not his strong part, here even pointers to pointers.